# Как повернуть элемент на 90° с помощью jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, transform

Мне нужно проиграть 3D анимацию с помощью jquery. Нужно, чтобы элемент поворачивался на 90° по оси Y.

Для понятности приведу план анимации: от 0° до 90° потом от -90° до 0°.

Comment: "по оси Y" - "вокруг оси Y"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если без jQuery? Ну или просто добавить нужный класс?

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 2em;
  height: 4em;
  width: 4em;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: silver;
  animation: rot 7s linear infinite;
  line-height: 4em;
  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes rot {
    0% { transform: rotateY( 0deg); }
   50% { transform: rotateY(90deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateY( 0deg); }
}
```

```html
<div>Text</div>
```

Comment: Вы гений. Спасибо.

Comment: Да вот только всяравно у меня не работает почемуто

Comment: @Ezdrael, http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d

Comment: Все дело в том что ето раньше работало

Comment: @Ezdrael, значит ищи баг.

Comment: Странно, на сайте работакт а в браузерах нет.

Comment: А как сделать чтобы в перспективе 3д нормально работало?

Comment: @Ezdrael, это же и есть 3d.

Comment: Нет. Я о том что если добавить transform-style: preserve-3d; то оно не будет поворачиваться так как нужно.

Comment: @Ezdrael, ну так не добавляй.

Comment: В обшем ерунда какаято у меня выходит. Прийдется всю страницу переписивать

Answer (score 0):

jQuery тут особо не при чем, вам в любом случае понадобится CSS3.

Вот 2 варианта реализации поворота: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/L838azrz/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Test 1
  var fwd = false;
  var timer = null;
  var counter = 0;
  var $test1 = $(".test1");
  var speed = 4;

  $test1.on("click", function() {
    fwd = !fwd;

    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      if (fwd) {
        counter += speed;
      } else {
        counter -= speed;
      }

      if (counter < 0) {
        counter = 0;
        clearInterval(timer);
      }

      if (counter > 90) {
        counter = 90;
        clearInterval(timer);
      }

      $test1.css("transform", "rotate(" + counter + "deg)");
    }, 20)
  });






  // Test 2
  $(".test2").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 100px;
}
.test1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}
.test2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.test2.active {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test1">Больше на JS</div>
<div class="test2">Больше на CSS</div>
```